# css buttons: forcing them to size themselves automatically

Tags: html, css

i have these buttons on the top of the page:

HOME, BUYING PROPERTY, SELLING PROPERTY, COMMUNITY INFO ETC..

1. i would like it so that when i add more buttons, they automatically size themselves and i dont have to resize each individual one.
2. also i would like them to take up the entire top bar

here is the code

```
#cssmenu_moo_menu {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background-attachment:scroll;
background-color:#006198;
background-image:url(../images/moomenu.png);
background-position:50% top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
float:left;
height:35px;
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:none;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
margin-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
padding-top:0;
}
```

i am wondering if the following might be answering my question?

[CSS Horizontal Navigation, Dynamic Width Buttons, 100% Width, Img Backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501364/css-horizontal-navigation-dynamic-width-buttons-100-width-img-backgrounds)

Comment: Could you give an example of the code you're already written?

Comment: Just make a class for the buttons in the bar and add that class to the new buttons when you make them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people might complain, but a table will size them automatically for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hi</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Pick Me 1" style="width:100%;" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Pick Me 2" style="width:100%;" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Pick Me 3" style="width:100%;" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just add a new table data element for each new button.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with pure CSS (on a semantic and crossbrowser-compatible manner, thus leaving respectively `<table>` and `display: table;` outside). You'll have to bring some shot of JavaScript ([jQuery](http://jquery.com)?) in, which has however the caveat that this might lead to "wtf?" experiences as the enduser may *see* the items (or buttons as you call it) being resized on the fly while the page loads.

I would rather stick to altering the CSS on every add/remove of the item. Live with it.

Comment: With a javascript solution, your end user will also have a varying experience based on whether they have javascript enabled or not also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Buying Property</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Selling Property</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Community Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
    display: block;
}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: .2em;
    background: #CCC;
    /* etc */
}

.clearfix:after {
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}

* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

**EDIT:**

Since there is no pure-CSS solution, it would be better to iterate through the menu-items with PHP:

```
$pages = array('Page 1' => 'page1.php', 'Page 2' => 'page2.php');
$numPages = count($pages);
$width = ceil(99/$numPages); // 99% is the maximum width, 100% could cause some problems with the last menu item
foreach($pages as $title => $link){
    echo '<li style="width: ' . $width . '"><a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Did you actually *understand* his question? :)

Comment: See point 2. of his question. The "buttons" must together accumulate up to a width of 100% of the parent element. In your example, give `ul` a fixed width or a `100%` width and try to get all `li` elements to fill up the space, regardless of the amount of `li` elements, *without* changing the CSS.